# Firefox addons don't work at all

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, firefox-extensions

I've installed Autofill addon, it appears in the main taskbar now but when I click on it nothing happens:

[image]

I don't see any new items in the context menu either. I've installed another similar addon and it seems to be unusable as well. Reloading the page doesn't help. How am I supposed to use addons on Firefox if none of them are working?